# Getting controller_manager to recognize new controller

Tags: ros, ros-controllers, ros-control, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to write a new controller as simply as possible and get it working with Gazebo, but now that I have everything set up, my new controller does not seem to register with controller_manager. I am new to ROS, ros_control, and cmake, so I am struggling to troubleshoot.

When launching my controller, parameters load successfully, but I receive an error for each controller:

> Could not load controller 'joint1_position_controller' because controller type 'artbot_control_new/CustomController' does not exist.

What is necessary for controller_manager to recognize the new class? In my workspace I have:

1. Robot description and gazebo packages for a robot very similar to [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control). Works correctly with existing ros_controllers examples.
2. A control package with the following:

- CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files specifying controller_interface, hardware_interface, pluginlib.
- In src, a controller class .cpp file based on [this example](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/controller_interface), with the namespace, class name, and pluginlib arguments updated.
- A .yaml config file and launchfile specifying this package and the new controller.

I could be missing something very basic, but I am not sure where to look next. Let me know what information I can provide.

I'm using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207745/getting-controller_manager-to-recognize-new-controller/) by [ColinG](https://answers.ros.org/users/22259/coling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add an `export` section to your pkg manifest? Something like (from [position_controllers/package.xml](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/2630760d4e338d0cff94ef457b9691c9cc622f9a/position_controllers/package.xml#L23-L25)):

```
<package>
  ..
  <export>
    <controller_interface plugin="${prefix}/artbot_control_plugins.xml"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

Without that export, your package will not be considered a package providing a controller plugin, which is what the manager will look for.

See also [wiki/pluginlib - Registering Plugin with ROS Package System](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib#pluginlib.2BAC8-pluginlib_groovy.Registering_Plugin_with_ROS_Package_System).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ColinG](https://answers.ros.org/users/22259/coling/) on 2015-04-24**:
This is exactly what I was missing! The controller is functioning now as expected. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.